# Azure Data Factory - Calling a REST call per row of imported data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to use Azure Data Factory to do the following...

Read in a CSV file, do a Google Maps Geocode lookup based on addresses in that file, and dump the results in Azure SQL.  I've been able to read from CSV and dump into Azure SQL, it's calling the rest service that I'm not sure how to do.

Can anyone give me guidance on the best way to do this?  Thank you!

Comment: Just a comment, if you are using Azure, you might want to consider using Azure maps instead of Google Maps. It will likely be cheaper and would be a server to server call within Azure which will likely be faster too. See https://azure.com/maps for more info.

Comment: Yes, I'm a fan of Bing Maps and have used it in the past.  I was plugged into this project late in the game, probably will persuade them over time to migrate most of their cloud services needs to Azure/Bing.

Comment: Just for clarity, Azure Maps and Bing Maps are separate products.

Comment: I actually played with the Azure Maps service during Microsoft Pi Day event.  I'm not really sure how it differs from the Bing Maps API however.

Comment: There are a lot of similar services currently, but if you dig deeper into the APIs you will see the difference. Also the licensing for Azure Maps is much more simpler. If you are using Azure, Microsoft recommends using Azure Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Use [LookUp Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to read the content of csv file.

```
@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output
```

2.Use [ForEach Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) to loop the output of LookUp Activity.

[image]

3.Inside ForEach Activity,use copy activity. The source dataset please set [REST Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#dataset-properties) to call geocode rest api. Configure the per row as body content.

```
@item()
```

[image]

4.Configure the azure sql database as sink dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jay.  I will attempt to implement today!

Comment: I'm getting there, but I have a question.  Copy Data activity requires me to select a Source dataset from the dropdown.  It does not give me the option to use the output from the Web lookup.  Can you give me a hint on this?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Jay.  I am able to do my per row geocode lookups.  My next question... I'm migrating lots of data from the source to the sink in addition to the geocoded data.  How can I move all that extra data to the sink?